# Scala dynamic type

Tags: scala, generics, types, type-parameter

```
object BugFixProject {

  def main (args: Array[String]) {
    val repoWithEntities = Seq(
      (ARepo, Seq(A("", ""), A("", ""))),
      (BRepo, Seq(B("", ""), B("", "")))
    )

    printall(repoWithEntities)
  }

  def printall[Entity](pairs: Seq[(BaseRepo[Entity], Seq[Entity])]) : Seq[String] = {
    pairs.map { t =>
      val repo = t._1
      val entities = t._2

      entities.map(repo.toString(_))
    }.flatten
  }

}

case class A(foo: String, bar: String){}
case class B(foo: String, bar: String){}

trait BaseRepo[X] {
  def toString(x: X) : String = x.toString
}

object BRepo extends BaseRepo[B] {}
object ARepo extends BaseRepo[A] {}
```

printall should be used like stated in the main method. But then I get the following error during compilation:

```
Error:(12, 9) no type parameters for method printall: (pairs: Seq[(BaseRepo[Entity], Seq[Entity])])Seq[String] exist so that it can be applied to arguments (Seq[(BaseRepo[_ >: B with A <: Product with Serializable], Seq[Product with Serializable])])
 --- because ---
argument expression's type is not compatible with formal parameter type;
 found   : Seq[(BaseRepo[_ >: B with A <: Product with Serializable], Seq[Product with Serializable])]
 required: Seq[(BaseRepo[?Entity], Seq[?Entity])]
        printall(repoWithEntities)
        ^
```

And

```
Error:(12, 18) type mismatch;
 found   : Seq[(BaseRepo[_ >: B with A <: Product with Serializable], Seq[Product with Serializable])]
 required: Seq[(BaseRepo[Entity], Seq[Entity])]
        printall(repoWithEntities)
                 ^
```

I do not understand the error messages. Is it maybe possible that in

```
def printall[Entity]
```

Entity can only be 1 specific type?

Comment: You don't need the type parameter `Entity` if you know what's going into the method. It's not really clear what you're trying to do here, have you tried rewriting your code a bit to make it more clearer?

Comment: Mhhm. I do not know how to clarify...
I want `printall`to be callable with `repoWithEntities`, but do not know, how the method signature has to look like...
`printall` should be callable with a value of type `Seq[(BaseRepo[Entity], Seq[Entity])]` with "Entity" just being there to show that a Tuple must contain a BaseRepo with a Sequence of the same type. Like shown in the example, repoWithEntities can have tuples containing different repos of differnt types.

Comment: In any single call to `printall`, yes, `Entity` must be some type in particular.

Comment: Is it possible to change the signiture so I am not limited to one type per call?

Answer (score 0):

Try making your function call in a very generic way as shown below

```
  def printall(pairs: Seq[(BaseRepo[_], Seq[_])]) : Seq[String] = {
```

This way you will be able to call `printall` method with either `BRepo` or `ARepo` object.

Comment: But then it would be possible to have a pair `(ARepo, Seq(B("","")))` which should not be allowed in `printall`. That may be the reason your solution is not compileable.